# Hard linking within makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to create two hard links to my target program. My target program is `foo`, and I want to create two hardlinks to foo, one called `baz` and the other called `bar`. Currently my makefile looks like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
HOME = /my/home/dir
SOURCES = main.c bar.c baz.c datastructure.c ${HOME}/addNodes.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
TARGET = foo
LN_F = ln -f

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bar: ${TARGET}
    ${LN_F} ${TARGET} bar

baz: ${TARGET}
    ${LN_F} ${TARGET} baz
```

The problem is that I now have to create hardlinks to foo manually, by entering `"ln -s foo bar"` and `"ln -s foo baz"`

Comment: minor point: ln -s is a symbolic link, not a hard link. You probably do not want hard links though. Did you try just adding `ln -s $(TARGET) bar` after the `${CC}`... line?

Comment: @GregBowser Oh ok, I didn't realize -s was a symbolic link. But I definitely want a hard link because I want bar and baz to represent the same program as foo, but just have different names.

Comment: A symbolic link will do that. e.g on my system: `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`, which is basically what you're looking to do. Symbolic links are the way to go 99% of the time. Anyway, just adding the `ln -s...` line in the `$(TARGET)` target should do the trick.

Comment: actually there would be two ln -s lines, one for bar and one for baz in the processing block for the $(TARGET) target

Comment: The "processing block" is called "recipe".  And, it is not a good idea to have side effects in recipes. Each recipe should write one file and one file only, its target.  So, it is not a good idea to create both the target and the link in one recipe.  There should be separate recipes.  That is the good style for makefiles.

Comment: @Apollo: Right, and that's what a symbolic link is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go with symbolic links:

```
TARGET = foo
AUX1   = bar
AUX2   = baz
LN_S   = ln -s -f

all: ${TARGET} ${AUX1} ${AUX2}

${TARGET}: $(OBJECTS)                                                           
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^                                                    

${AUX1}: ${TARGET}
    ${LN_S} ${TARGET} ${AUX1}

${AUX2}: ${TARGET}
    ${LN_S} ${TARGET} ${AUX2}
```

If you go with hard links, you will use `ln -f` (without the `-s`).  Note that once upon a (very) long time ago, the `-f` was not supported by `ln` (and in those days, `-s` wasn't an option either — I'm talking about that long ago), and a rule like these linking rules would use `rm -f` to remove the link before running the `ln` command.

You can also write the link lines using generic macros `$@` and `$?` (these are the reliable, POSIX-supported macros):

```
${AUX2}: ${TARGET}
    ${LN_S} $? $@
```

This works sanely because there is only one prerequisite for `${AUX2}`; if there were more than one prerequisite, `$?` would not work — be careful.

Comment: That is incorrect.  There are two subtle errors in your rules for symlinks:  first, the dependency on target should be order-only, second `ln -f` flag must be used to correctly support Make `-B` option.

Comment: the ${AUX1|2} targets should actually perform 'rm  $@' before trying to create the symbolic link(s)  also suggest the link line be: ${LN_S} -f $^ $@

Comment: @user3629249 why should they remove? If you have a good reason, tell me so I can learn.  In general, in makefiles it is best to avoid `rm` things and then making them again, because, that changes the directory, and there may be targets that depend on the directory.  It should always be better to try and just replace the file in place, without momentarily removing it.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Please clarify.  What do you mean by 'order only'?  It isn't part of POSIX `make` as far as I know.  As to the other, then yes you can use `-f` and it will work better with (non-standard) option `-B` which is supported by GNU `make`. You can also write the rule with `rm -f` to remove the link before creating the link.  That was necessary many (many, many) years ago before `ln` acquired the `-f` option.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I modified my makefile (please see edit) however it still does not produce the hardlinks I desire. Any idea why? Thanks for taking the tim to answer this question, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you say `make bar baz` it will create the links.  If you just say `make`, it creates only the first target in the `makefile`.  Note that my version has a rule `all:` that depends on `foo`, `bar` and `baz` as the first rule, so when you type `make`, it creates all the depends of `all`.  With GNU `make`, you could add `.PHONEY: all clean` to tell `make` that they are phony targets — not real files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well I assume GNU Make, which is the what the vast majority of people are using.  "order only" is part of GNU Make.  I think GNU Make is what the OP wanted.  If you disagree, then I apologize for bothering you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  All right, let's not assume GNU Make then.  Do you agree that with your solution, any change to $(TARGET) will trigger re-creating the links with the new timestamp, and that, in turn, might create a cascade of other rebuilds.  For no reason whatsoever.  Because, as I said, a change to $(TARGET) _should_not_ trigger any rebuild of the links.  As to the alternative to `-f` being `rm`, I disagree.  `rm` things in recipes is a bad idea. Because, it changes the directory for a moment. There could be targets depending on the directory.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: No, I don't agree that a change to `${TARGET}` will cause symlinks to be recreated.  The reason is that `make` stats the file, not the link, and the file is the target file, so the link is up to date when it is checked, so no consequential updates occur either.  With hard links, it depends how the target is rewritten.  If the hard links are preserved (the original file is simply truncated and written, not removed and recreated), then that too is also safe.  It depends on the process that creates the target though.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: If targets depend on the age of a directory, they're delicate beyond belief — IMO, the design of the dependencies is faulty.  I'm not saying you can't create makefiles with such dependencies, but I've never found a compelling use case for such a dependency, precisely because almost any change can modify the time on the directory and affect the whole world. If you do use such dependencies, then you may have to use the `-f` option, though I'm of the opinion that it is unlikely to be significantly different from `rm -f` followed by `ln` except that two processes are run instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your post and comments explains why hard links are needed.  So I will continue the line of my predecessor trying to show you how to do this with soft links.

The correct way to create a symlink to target in a makefile is like this:

```
TARGET := foo
LINK := bar

$(LINK): Makefile | $(TARGET)
    ln -sf $| $@
```

The dependency must be order-only because you don't depend on the changes to target, you only care that it exists, so you don't have a hanging link, which is a bad thing.

`-f` option is necessary to support GNU Make `-B` option.